# can UAC prevent reading a certficate?

Tags: windows-7, uac, certificate

Weird question with, hopefully, a short answer.
I have this application running on windows 7 that calls a webservice through a .NET DLL. To be able to do that it needs to read some certificates, placed in Local computer-> personal and Local computer-> Trusted Root....

If i run this application with UAC turned on, I get an error and the web-service guy is able to see in the log that we say hello, that he send their certificate but then we never send ours and the connection is cancelled.

If I turn off UAC.. it works.

But, can anyone tell me wether or not UAC really can prevent the user from reading a Certificate or if the problem actually is something else?

EDIT: No luck with this one. The strangest part is that it looks like I still can't read my certificate even if it's put in the "current user" keystore? Why have such a keystore if the user isn't allowed to read it anyway?
It's of course possible that the UAC is blocking something else but I can't figure out what that would be since the LOG says I'm creating the tunnel and say "hello" to the web-service.. but I don't send my certificate..

Regards

Comment: Do you esclate the permissions have the process before you send the certificate?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but it works with UAC turned off as said, so I suppose not anyone can read certficates from Local computer when it's turned on.

Comment: Is your application requesting read *and* write permissions to the certificate store, or just read? requesting read *and* write permissions at the same time should almost *certainly* require elevated privileges, and in that case UAC would be behaving as designed.

Comment: Nope, all I do is read the certificate, exchange it with the web-service and receive my XML. Tomorrow, I'll try to put the certficate in the "Current user" store and see if it makes any difference

Comment: @elwis - Look into how to escalate the permissions of a process.  One way is to use "run as administrator".

Comment: So, I tried to put my certificates in Current User's keystore and turned on UAC. No effect, it is still unable to exchange certificates:
(weird, I thought current user could access it's own certificates but No). Will read about escalated permissions, I only hope it won't require any "confirm" buttons since this is a service

Comment: I tried this one, but it triggers the "Confirm dialog" when I run it, I doubt that will be accepted, even if the DLL is allowed to elevate the motherprocess permissions
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/KB981778